# Iterate existing "for loop" until convergence

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, iteration

I would like to iterate an existing for loop so many times that when I take the average of the resulting list, they converge. I am unsure of how to do this and appreciate suggestions.Looping to infinity or a really large number? Is there a more elegant method?

Thank you.

Comment: You must use a `while` loop. `while some_cond: do_something()`.

Comment: While loop with convergence check ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While looping to infinity (with `for loop in itertools.count():`) would work, there doesn't seem to be any reason to make things that complicated, since you aren't planning to *use* that counter.

If you just want to loop until a condition is true, use a `while` loop:

```
while not converged():
    # your code here
```

If you can't conveniently put that `converged()` test at the head of the loop, just loop forever and test in the body:

```
while True:
    # your code here
    if converged():
        break
```

I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "converged" here, but it sounds like it might involve the results being close enough to the previous loop's results? If so, you'll need to keep those previous results around to test against.

For example:

```
lastavg = None
while True:
    # your code
    avg = statistics.mean(FinalLengths)
    if lastavg is not None and math.isclose(avg, lastavg):
        break
    lastavg = avg
```

Or maybe you want to know whether the change was in the same direction as and smaller than the previous change? Then you'd need to keep the two previous averages, or the previous average and the previous change. Whatever you want should be easy to do.

Comment: @BenSmert You explained all the background details, but left out the important part: What do you mean "so that the mean converges"? What's your intended test for that? I mean, the literal definition is in terms of all natural numbers > some N, which takes infinite time to prove or disprove, so people usually use some heuristic that can be tested in finite time.